# Cannot deploy SharePoint Framework packages anymore after upgrade to SPFx 1.6

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Cannot deploy SharePoint Framework packages anymore after upgrade to SPFx 1.6. Few blogs suggested that its because of the webApiPermissionRequests crossing more than 255 characters. Is there any solution or fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new issue which is coming from the sharePoint side. People are discussing about it, you can follow discussion from the below link

refer to this https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2624